# NodeJS HTTP: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ionic2

I am developing on Ionic Framework `2.0.0-beta.4`. My node version is `v4.4.7`.
I am trying to use **NodeJS http**.

My code:

```
    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
      host: 'www.google.com',
      port: 80,
      path: '/index.html',
    };

    http.get(options, function(res) {
      console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

      res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
      });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
```

The error i am getting is:

> Fetch API cannot load
> http://www.google.com/index.html. No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Got error: Failed to fetch

I have tried searching online but the solutions are not working for me. Does anybody have a suggestion?

**EDIT :**
I am running Node.Js on an Android application.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, that error is browser-specific, it relates to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which is only enforced in browsers. I just tried it, and that code does not produce that error in NodeJS v4 or NodeJS v6.

Comment: I got __`302 Moved`__ error.. Not the one you have specified...

Comment: `http.get('http://www.google.co.in', function(res) {` works fine...

Comment: @Rayon Think i was not clear in my question. I have tried running `node http.js` which will give me the `302 Moved` error. But when running on my android application, it gives a the `no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error

Comment: @Huiting – It is not related to the code you have shared by any means...